# Cant access variable value in php

Tags: php

I'm working on simple app that add array items on button click and display the values on click.

My problem is after adding the items to array I cant display the values.

Hope you help me.

**HTML**

```
<form action="" method="POST">
    <button name="save">save</button>
    <button name="display">display</button>
</form>
```

**PHP**

```
$arr = array();

    if (isset($_POST['save'])) {

        $items = array('Mark', '12', 'Japan');

        array_push($arr, $items);

    }

    if (isset($_POST['display'])) {

        print_r($arr);

    }
```

Comment: And what does output `print_r($arr)` ?

Comment: the Items that was push on save

Comment: The reason this isn't working is because when clicking on the save button you filled the `$arr` variable with the items and never saved them, but than when you clicked on the display button it recreated the `$arr` array as an empty list.

To do this, on the save button you need to store that data somewhere like a database or a file, and than on the display button retrieve that data first and than display it.

Comment: You don't actually "save" your array after adding values to it

Comment: use array merge function of php instead of array_push

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try to use [PHP sessions](http://php.net/manual/en/book.session.php). This example is very basic, but may help you to understand how to preserve your data across subsequent accesses:

```
<?php
session_start();

if (isset($_POST['save'])) {
    echo 'Save'.'<br>';
    $items = array('Mark', '12', 'Japan');
    $_SESSION['SimpleArray'] = array();
    array_push($_SESSION['SimpleArray'], $items);
}

if (isset($_POST['display'])) {
    echo 'Display'.'<br>';
    print_r($_SESSION['SimpleArray']);
    echo '<br>';
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way that you can use a hidden input element to keep updating your POST array with the added information.

Use this:

```
<?php

//Check to make sure there is a value set for the hidden field in the post array.
  if(isset($_POST['myArray']) && $_POST['myArray']){

  //If there is we are going to decode and unserialize it and pass it to the $arr varaible.
  $arr = unserialize(base64_decode($_POST['myArray'])); 

  }

  //Check to see if you hit the save button.
  if (isset($_POST['save'])) {

    //We did so we are adding an element to the $arr array.
    $arr[] = array('Mark', '12', 'Japan');

  }

  //Check to see if we want to display all the data from hitting the save
  //button multiple times.
  if (isset($_POST['display'])) {

    //We did so lets print out the array of what we have "saved so far."
    print_r($arr);

  }

  //Checking to make sure we have an array.  If we do we are going to 
  //serialize and encode the array so we can pass it to the hidden input element.
  if(isset($arr)){

    //serialize and encode.
    $arr = base64_encode(serialize($arr));

  } else {

    //Nothing happened.  Pass nothing to the hidden input element.
    $arr = '';

  }


?>


<form action="" method="POST">
    <button name="save">save</button>
    <button name="display">display</button>
    <input type="hidden" name="myArray" value="<?php echo $arr; ?>">
</form>
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

It is two different conditions.

So when you are clicking on the save button, everything is working correctly and `$arr` is contain needed value but now, when you are clicking to the `display` button, you are re-submitting this form again and the first condition isn't working correctly because server forgets about your `$arr`. It is completely different requests.

Use this code:

```
$arr = array();

if (isset($_POST['save'])) {

    $items = array('Mark', '12', 'Japan');

    array_push($arr, $items);
    echo 'one <br>';

}

if (isset($_POST['display'])) {
    echo 'two <br>';
    print_r($arr);

}
```

And you will see that `one` isn't showing once you click the `display` button.

You can use `session` as the simplest solution for this.

Comment: This is more of a debugging help than an actual answer. Maybe add a sample example using sessions. It seems OP is a newbie to PHP